# Linux script to go into all folders and perform command

Tags: linux, script

Hi I have several folders in my directory. I would like to perform this command in all of them:

wc -l * > total

Is there a way that a script can do this?

Comment: Are their subdirectories as well and would you want to run that command in the subdirectories too if they exist?

Comment: Use this as a starting point. `find . -type d -print | while read dn; do (cd $dn; echo "command in $dn"); done` You'll figure how to append the per-directory output to the text file, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
find /YOUR/ROOT/DIR -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \; > total
```

If you need a `total` file for each (sub)directory, then you'll need to loop this call:

```
find /YOUR/ROOT/DIR -type d | while read
do
   # Change '/' to '_' in dir name
   NAME=$(echo "$REPLY" | sed -e 's#/#_#g')
   wc -l "$REPLY" > "total.$NAME"
done
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line read "-type d" ?

Comment: I think no. Question wants to run `wc -l *` in every directory which means running `wc -l` for every file in every directory. So this answer finds all files and runs `wc -l` for all of them i guess

Comment: The first line finds **all files** recursively on all subdirectories, saving the result of `wc` to only one `total` file. The other code block is for having a `total` file for each subdirectory.